# Using custom Swing class for "Surround With"

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, form-designer, rsyntaxtextarea

I have a custom [`JTextArea`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) and want to surround it with a custom [`JScrollPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html).

Unfortunately, the form designer only suggests using the regular `JScrollPane` for surrounding and doesn't seem to give me the option to define a custom object [like the palette would](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/placing-non-palette-components-or-forms.html).

Specifically, I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea) project's `RSyntaxTextArea` surrounded with a `RTextScrollPane`.

Comment: This is [not supported](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6932).

Comment: Disappointing if this is true. It has been years...

Comment: As the developer who used to be responsible for this feature in IntelliJ IDEA, I'm quite sure that this is true. The UI Designer is no longer under active development, so it's extremely unlikely that this will ever be implemented.

Comment: @yole:
Oh, thank you. What would you use instead? Doing it by hand or some plugin?

Comment: One option is to surround with a regular scroll pane and then to use the "Morph component" action to transform it to your custom scroll pane.

Comment: @yole:
"Morph component" is greyed out for the surrounding `JScrollPane`. I already tried that

Comment: `Doing it by hand ` - always. Don't let an IDE generate your GUI code. The generated code will not be portable if you ever use a different IDE. Use the IDE to help with compiling, debugging etc. Spend you time learning Java, not the IDE.

Comment: @camickr: I rather not have hundreds of lines of "trashy" GUI code/waste plenty of time on this and instead concentrate most of my time on actually implementing the logic. The old Eclipse times were horrible with GUI design since it also looked bad. I do like the way IntelliJ IDEA handles this and I'm not switching any time soon since it's the best IDE...

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza, `I rather not have hundreds of lines of "trashy" GUI code` - exactly the code generated by an IDE is lengthy. The code you write will be far more logical and easy to maintain.